# What is rubinius? I saw it in Ruby Weekly but I don't understand what it is after reading the website

Tags: ruby

Is it a thing that let you understand ruby core? http://rubini.us/

Comment: OMG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubinius

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a project to provide an alternative Ruby interpreter/compiler. Essentially an optimization effort to make Ruby run faster after the regular code is translated into machine code. It is likely something to look at if you have a complex Ruby app that has heavy use - and at that point if you're running into a wall with what Ruby can do, you could try this alternative interpreter to make your code faster.

Answer (score 3):

Rubinius is an implementation of the Ruby programming language, just like MRI, YARV, JRuby, IronRuby, MacRuby, MagLev, SmallRuby, tinyrb, RubyGoLightly, BlueRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET, IoRuby, Cardinal, Carbone, Aluminium, Smalltalk.Rb, MetaRuby, Rite, RedSun, HotRuby and all the others.